# Running @hapi/hapi giving error "#meetings = null SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Was using

@hapi/hapi : ^20.0.0

node.js : v10.19.0

Got the following error stack

```
|     #meetings = null;
|     ^
| 
| SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
|     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
|     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
|     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
|     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
|     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Was using the following code

> 'use strict';
>
> ```
> const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
>
> const init = async () => {
>
>     const server = Hapi.server({
>         port: 5000,
>         host: 'localhost'
>     });
>
>     await server.start();
>     console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
> };
>
> process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
>
>     console.log(err);
>     process.exit(1);
> });
>
> init();
> ```

Comment: Can you share your code? What exactly are you running?

Comment: Sure, I am adding it

Comment: I think you are trying to use private Class fields which are only supported in Node 12+
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: Sure, checking on Node12+

Comment: @KostasX Yes worked on node-v12.18.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should upgrade the Node version to 12+ which supports [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) like `#meetings`.

---

**References:** [Table of Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded node version from v10.19.0 to v12.18.3 and it worked

Got the reference from https://github.com/outmoded/sntp/issues/37